# Forcing www to a sub domain in .htaccess cause 500 internal server error

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomain

Suppose My domain is

- example.com pointed to the server root (public_html)

I have created a sub domain

- dev.example.com Pointed to the directory  (public_html/development)

I wanted to always open my both site (main + subdomain) with www prefix

for that I place the below code to .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Main site working fine its redirect **domain.com** to https://www.example.com

But **dev.example.com** redirects to https://www.dev.example.com/development and cause 500 Internal Server Error.
It should be redirected to https://www.dev.example.com instead of https://www.dev.example.com/development

Where I am going wrong.

I tried different Codes in .htaccess but nothiing works.

Comment: Can you reuse above rule in `development/.htaccess` and test it after clearing browser cache.

Comment: thank you so much  @anubhava its work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer to that it might help someone facing similar problem.

Move above rule in `development/.htaccess` so that per directory directive `RewriteRule` sets `$1` value relative to `development` directory instead of `public_html` directory.

Make sure to test it after clearing browser cache.

Comment: may I know logic /reason behind the solution

Comment: Yes if you note, I have already added reason of this behavior. `.htaccess` is per directory directives. When we capture URI using `RewriteRule ^(.*)$` then `.*` captures value **relative** to the directory this .htaccess belongs to.